# Clojure how to return all vectors in the list

Tags: vector, collections, clojure

my function returns some vectors inside list and I need to escape from that list and return vectors.

My main function works like that and return vector inside list.

```
(defn destruct-cart-items [my-cart]
  (for [[user product stock-amount] my-cart]
    [:tr [:td user] [:td product] [:td stock-amount]]
    )
  )
=>
([:tr [:td "bar"] [:td "mammut"] [:td 1]]
 [:tr [:td "bar"] [:td "mammut"] [:td 1]]
 [:tr [:td "bar"] [:td "mammut"] [:td 1]]
 [:tr [:td "bar"] [:td "mammut"] [:td 1]])
```

I need return vectors like that--->

```
 [:tr [:td "bar"] [:td "mammut"] [:td 1]]
 [:tr [:td "bar"] [:td "mammut"] [:td 1]]
 [:tr [:td "bar"] [:td "mammut"] [:td 1]]
 [:tr [:td "bar"] [:td "mammut"] [:td 1]]
```

How can I do that in different ways?

Why I need like that

```clj
(clerk/html [:table
             [:tr [:th "User"] [:th "Product"] [:th "Stock Amount"]]
             (destruct-cart-items @!my-cart)])
```

I will use returned data inside the HTML element.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [unquote-splicing](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/unquote-splicing):

```
(clerk/html `[:table
              [:tr 
               [:th "User"] 
               [:th "Product"] 
               [:th "Stock Amount"]]
              ~@(destruct-cart-items @!my-cart)])
```

Comment: That worked for me, and it looks like a very cool way to use in HTML items!

Comment: Yes, this is the way to solve this kind of problem. The only way a function can return multiple items is if they are wrapped in a sequence (list or vector), but if you need to remove that wrapper when building another data structure, unquote-splicing is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

```
(into [:table
           [:tr [:th "User"]]]
        (destruct-cart-items @!my-cart))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with clerk specifically, but it is a pretty crummy reimplementation of hiccup if it even requires an `into`. Hiccup has always "seen through" lists, handling `[:table [:tr ...] (for [...] [:tr ...])]` just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure has no notion of returning multiple items from a function. The idiom here is to return a collection of the items and then use that collection.

In your case, you can simply add a call to `into`:

```
(clerk/html (into [:table ...] (destruct-cart-items ...)))
```

As an alternative, perhaps the Hiccup variant that Clerk supports has a notion of fragments - in that case, you might be able to create a fragment and pass it as a child to `[:table ...]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I going to try both alternatives as soon as possible. Have a good day!